# telerik appbuilder oAuth popup doesn't close

Tags: oauth, azure-mobile-services, telerik-appbuilder

I am using Azure Mobile service's oAuth to authenticate users with their facebook/google/twitter in a hybrid JS app. When azure client's 'login' method is called, it opens a popup window to show the selected oAuth providers login screen where user can enter login credentials. After the authentication is over, this popup usually closes, when I test on Chrome Ripple emulator or on my device.

I test my code also on Telerik Appbuilder, because it gives more 'real-device' environment compared to Chrome Ripple (some may differ on this point, but I don't want to get into that argument and that's actually not the point of this question).
The issue I am facing when testing on Telerik Appbuilder device emulator is - the oAuth popup doesn't close once user is done logging in - wondering if anyone may have any clue about this issue? many thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this?

Comment: no, haven't found any fix for this so far. So I gave it up and test on ripple. Now I use appbuilder just to build the app , not for testing the app, and then I test it on my mobile device, where this issue, of oAuth window not closing, doesn't happen. (btw, I am using the 'browser' version of Appbuilder )